# multiple comparisons, and separate groups

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

Say I have a population of 5,000 objects.  Each object has a length M > 100 feature vector (real numbers).  The 5,000 objects can be split into 3 group: A,B,C.  These groups are disjoint, non-trivial (> 100 objects) subsets of the total population of 5,000 objects.  where size(A) + size(B) + size(C) = 5,000.

Consider comparing each component of the M-length feature vector for A vs. B  This results in M p-values.  I account for multiple comparisons by applying FDR, as usual.

However, a priori, I am interested in all comparisons.  That is:  for each pairwise grouping A vs. B, B vs C, and A vs C,  I want test if each component of the M-length feature vector is different.

**Question 1:**

**Should I perform FDR separately** (i.e. FDR on the p-values of A vs. B,  FDR on the p-values of B vs. C, FDR on the p-values of A vs. C) ,  **or should I pool all of the p-values together (a length 3M vector) and *then* perform FDR?**

**Question 2:**

Given the theoretical basis/motivation of the multiple comparisons problem.  I believe I need to pool all the p-values together.  **Are the pairwise FDR computations still valid, regardless?**  For each pairwise consideration AvB, BvC, AvB also fulfills the FDR setting.

However, within A vs. B, the M hypothesis tests are mutually independent.  But when I pool all the p-values together, the 3M hypothesis tests are NOT independent (since A + B + C = the whole population).  **This seems to reject the notion that pairwise FDR values and "pooled" FDR values are both legitimate?**